# Handle pagination REST API

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I implemented a function calling a REST API. I defined my query, header, parameters.
I wasn't able to manage pagination with loadData() method. How can I achieve my second call to get the page 2 for example ? I tried the recursive way but it didn't work.
Here is an response example of HTTP GET request to REST API:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        ...
       }
        
],
"pageSize": 1000,
"currentPage": 1,
"lastPage": 3,
"totalObjectCount": 2789,
"truncated": false
```

}

The function I implemented :

```
    readRestAPI: function (sQuery) {
        var oDataModel = new JSONModel();
        oDataModel.setSizeLimit(2000);
        var oAuthModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("AuthToken");
        var oUserModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("User");
        var sCompanyName = oUserModel.getData().User[0].userCompanyName;
        var sAccountName = oAuthModel.getData().accountName;
        var sToken = oAuthModel.getData().token;
        var iPage = 1;
        var iPageSize = 1000; // Max object for one page in Query API is 1000
        var mParams = {
            "account": sAccountName,
            "company": sCompanyName,
            "query": sQuery,
            "page": iPage,
            "pageSize": iPageSize

        };
        var sURLQueryAPI = "/API/query/v1";
        var sType = "GET";
        var mHeaders = {
            "Authorization": sToken,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-Client-ID": sAccountName,
            "X-Client-Version": "1.0.0"
        };
        return oDataModel.loadData(sURLQueryAPI, $.param(mParams, true), true, sType, false, true, mHeaders).then(
            function (resData) {
            return oDataModel;
        });
    }
```

Could you please explain me how can I handle the pagination ( 1 to 3 for instance )? Thanks

Comment: `"currentPage": 1,
"lastPage": 1` strongly suggests that your data fits into a single request so there are no 2nd or 3rd page to request.

Comment: I see you edited it to `"lastPage": 3`, and then `"page": iPage` would be the place where you could ask for other pages (setting `iPage` to 2 for example). However as `"totalObjectCount": 2`, I have a feeling that you don't have 3 pages with 1000 items in each. A thing you can still try with a fistful of items only is requesting for single item pages, so `"page": 1, "pageSize": 1` and `"page": 2, "pageSize": 1`.

Comment: Thank @tevemadar for your reply. Indeed, now I got a an response with 2789 items.

Comment: The idea will be to call readRestAPI multiple time depending on the "lastPage" ? I tought recursive call would be a solution but I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: As you seem to have `Promise`s already, it may be possible to make this entire function `async`, and then just loop inside, `await`ing the individual pages inside the loop. If you don't know the number of pages (or items) at start, the loop could be a `do ... while()` one.

Comment: Could you please provide an example with async way if its possible? Thanks